# Can't get the points in a \parts to bold on right hand side

Tags: formatting

I would like to get the points on the right hand side of the page in bold on the same line as the question see below.

[image: points on right]

This is all I have so far. Not sure how to `\renew`

```
\begin{parts}
\part[2]
Expand $5x(3x^4-x^2)$
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{parts}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the relevant parts of your set-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are using `exam`

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}
\begin{parts}
\part[2]
Expand $5x(3x^4-x^2)$
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{parts}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much. This is perfect. could not find the \pointsinrightmargin and \pointformat

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Expand $5x(3x^4-x^2)$ \textbf{\dotfill} 1
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this might be a solution, I strongly suggest not to use `\bf`. This command is deprecated for 20 years now, like `\rm, \it, \tt` etc. Either use `\textbf{...}` or `\bfseries` if you can apply in a TeX group

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks! Your suggestion incorporated.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. I was using exam class. I also did not want the dotted lines straight after the question, but below it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\begin{document}
 Expand $5x(3x^4-x^2)$ \\ 
 \par
 \hdashrule{15cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt} \par \
 \vspace{0.4cm}
\hdashrule{15cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt} \par  
\vspace{0.4cm}
\hdashrule{15cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt} \par 
\vspace{0.4cm}
\hdashrule{15cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt} \par 
\end{document}
```

[image: dotlines]